# How to handle CA cert of Cockroach DB when deploying a Streamlit app to production?

Tags: python, authentication, cockroachdb

I am trying to deploy a streamlit app to production that uses CockroachDB as the backend.

To authenticate to CockroachDB, CA certs are needed in addition to the connection string credentials.

How should one handle CA certs for such a deployment setup?

I have tried including CA cert inside .env
But streamlit uses secrets.toml instead of .env.
I can manually convert the CA cert into text and put it in secrets.toml - but was wondering if there are alternatives to handle this